Transform RTF to HTML in python or other script
I need a script that would transform a RTF file to a HTML one, 1 RTF = 1 HTML, (pictures if any 64 encoded in the HTML).
In windows 10, I don't care of script language.
Actually, I tried to use my one year's old python script, that in theory takes a folder and converts all .RTF files to .HTML... but it does not work anymore
from glob import glob
import re
import os
import win32com.client as win32
import base64
import mammoth
from win32com.client import constants
from docx import Document
import sys

def change_word_format(file_path):
    word = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')
    doc = word.Documents.Open(file_path)
    doc.Activate()

    # Rename path with .docx
    new_file_abs = os.path.abspath(file_path)
    new_file_abs = re.sub(r'\.\w+$', '.docx', new_file_abs)

    # Save and Close
    word.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(
        new_file_abs, FileFormat=constants.wdFormatDocumentDefault
    )
    doc.Close(False)
    return new_file_abs

def convert_image(image):
    with image.open() as image_bytes:
        encoded_src = base64.b64encode(image_bytes.read()).decode("ascii")
    return {"src": f"data:{image.content_type};base64,{encoded_src}"}

def convert_docx_to_html(input_docx):    
    with open(input_docx, "rb") as docx_file:
        result = mammoth.convert_to_html(docx_file, convert_image=mammoth.images.img_element(convert_image))
        html = result.value
        
    output_html = os.path.splitext(input_docx)[0] + ".html"
    
    with open(output_html, "w", encoding="utf-8") as html_file:
        html_file.write(html)

    return output_html

def convert_rtf_to_html(input_rtf):
    input_docx = change_word_format(input_rtf)
    output_html = convert_docx_to_html(input_docx)
    os.remove(input_docx)  # Remove the intermediate docx file
    return output_html

def convert_rtf_files_to_html(start_path):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(start_path):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".rtf"):
                input_rtf = os.path.join(root, file)
                output_html_path = convert_rtf_to_html(input_rtf)
                print(f"Converted {input_rtf} to {output_html_path}")
                os.remove(input_rtf) # remove the source rtf

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_path = sys.argv[1]
    convert_rtf_files_to_html(start_path)


Could someone that know python help me find out the problem?
Among errors:

AttributeError: module 'win32com.gen_py.00020905-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x8x7' has no attribute 'CLSIDToClassMap'

or this one

File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\win32com\client\build.py", line 580, in _ResolveType
resultTypeInfo = itypeinfo.GetRefTypeInfo(subrepr)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147319765, 'Element not found.', None, None)

environment:

python==3.11 mammoth==1.6.0 pywin32==306 python-docx==0.8.11

